# iOS Chrome tables won't display block even with doctype declared

Tags: html, ios, css

My tables, and anything within, refuse to `display: block` on iOS Chrome (V. 39.9.2171.50), despite my having declared `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Here's the thing: tables display fine on desktop Chrome. And, on another site I worked on, tables work fine on iOS Chrome. I've checked several times--there aren't conflicting styles (otherwise, they should also create problems on desktop browsers). Even with inline styles, tables and their children table elements still display with user agent-defined styles. I'm at a loss. Might anyone know something aside from doctype that would default webkit do prefer user agent styles on tables?

EDIT:

```
<table class="test-table" style="display: block">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> Cell 1 </td>
            <td> Cell 2 </td>
            <td> Cell 3 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Cell 1 </td>
            <td> Cell 2 </td>
            <td> Cell 3 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Cell 1 </td>
            <td> Cell 2 </td>
            <td> Cell 3 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<style>
    .test-table, tbody, tr, td {
        display: block
    }
</style>
<script>
    (function($){
        alert($('.text-table').css('display')); // outputs: table;
    })(jQuery)
</script>
```

Comment: Show an example of your code, preferably minimal code that triggers the problem. Explain what you expect `display: block` to do and how actual rendering differs from that.

Comment: Hello @JukkaK.Korpela, I've added a simplied version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The class is called 'test-table' in html and css, but in js you use 'text-table'. Is this just a typo in the example?

Also, you could work with the statement !important in your css, like so:

```
.test-table, tbody, tr, td {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Another idea I have is styling the table object directly instead of the class, like this:

```
table, tbody, tr, td {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Let me know if some of this helped. ;)

Comment: Yes, 'text-table' was a typo only in the example. I ran into this problem a few months back, and so much code has passed through my eyes, I'm not really sure what the problem was any more. Somehow all my tables and their children elements display block just fine now.. nonetheless, thank you for your input.